# SQL Server Compact connection error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce

I've just done a clean install of Visual C# 2008 SP1, Sql Compact 3.5 SP1 was also installed during the process. Nevertheless, when I try to connect to an sdf file:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
```

I get an exception:

> Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8080. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.

I'm a bit confused, what should I install/update, then?

Comment: Can you **show us** your connection string?!?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Build 8080 is SP2, download and install both the x86 and x64 runtimes (if applicable) from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5783

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Downloading these new files did not help (I already had build 8080 SP2 installed.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you have not installed both the x86 and x64 runtimes

Comment: It amazes me how one app works (using same dlls and configs) and another throws this exception, this sqlce thing is load of troubles.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue.  I needed to link the desktop version (*\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop) of the dll, not the .NET reference and not the private version (*\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Private).  I did have both the x86 and x64 runtimes installed.

Comment: Sir...i owe you, you saved me twice :))

Answer (score 0):

Re-creating my connection to the db.sdf resolved this issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

Stuarts comment on ErikEJs answer worked for me. Change the dll reference from Private\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll to Desktop\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll once you have 3.5 SP2 installed.